# .NET application exports data to a remote Linux server

Tags: .net, mysql, linux

There is a MySQL database located on my remote Linux server. I have written a .NET Windows application to export data to this MySQL database. I want to know whether there will be any compatibility issues regarding .NET / Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a .NET data provider to access the database, you should have no issues, as the database engine communication protocol is the same regardless of the platform it is running on.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any difficulty, if you mean export the data, you meant something like 'Show Create table [some_table]' and 'select * from [some_table]'...the only thing I can think of is if the data contains binary...It might be better to base64 on the binary data to guarantee compatibility...other than that, you should be ok! Hope this helps. Tom

Comment: The data is read from a file and displayed on the DataGridView. After that I use Insert query to insert records, row-by-row, from the DataGridView to the remote MySQL DB.